# Android application update - how to?

Tags: android

What is the best way to let my users perform an application update?

Is there any way to force device reboot after the update? I'm asking this because my application registers some behavior on boot.

Please note, the application would not be published in the Market.

Update:

My app will be preinstalled on a set of ~100 handsets.
Should I periodically call a webservice that will inform the device about upgrade available, and then, redirect to an .apk file within a webkit view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the best way to let my users
>   perform an application update?

Via the same way they got the app on their device in the first place, presumably. If they are getting the app via firmware, they get app updates via firmware updates. If they are downloading your app via your Web site, they get app updates via your Web site.

> Is there any way to force device
>   reboot after the update?

No, thank goodness.

> I'm asking this because my application
>   registers some behavior on boot.

There is some way you can be notified that your package was updated, though I do not have the technique handy right now. Just run your on-boot logic there for the first round, then subsequent reboots (if any) will be handled by the on-boot logic itself.