# Is there a way to automatically update application on Android?

Tags: android, updates

I'm developing an application that will most likely be preinstalled on devices. It will be also available on Google Play. Is there a way to update those instances that are not downloaded through Google Play, since Google Play won't notify users about an update.

I was thinking about, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660740/android-application-update-how-to), trying to contact my site periodically, and when update is available, download it.

Is there a way to do this update automatically, or even silently, so that user doesn't have to do anything (like running the package manually). Or, when my site shows update is available, to offer users an update through Google Play, even though it's not installed through Market (EDIT: This Google play option would be preferable, because than users wouldn't have to check "allow install of non-Market sources".)

Comment: Pre-installed by working for or with a device vendor or carrier, presumably.

Comment: Yeah, most likely, but if it was in a corporate environment or something like that, one option would be to install originally by downloading from market, rather than having to role your own updater.

Comment: There is a possibility that seller will preinstall it on their devices, but they probably won't install it through the Market, and I'd like to enable users to upgrade without much hassle...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

i had the same issue, now i check at the start of my app if theres a new version in my configuration xml.

I compare the actual version with the tag "< app_version >1.1< /app_version >" of my configuration.xml
if its lower i ask with a custom AlertDialog if the user proceed with the upgrade

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW ,Uri.parse(myapk_link));
startActivity(intent);
```

after the download the user has to run the package manually.

if you choose the update from the Android market use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW ,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.package.name"));
startActivity(intent);
```

`com.package.name` must be the "package" of your app

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW ,Uri.parse("market://search?q=" + APP_NAME));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I had on my mind. Still a bit too complicated for the users... Thanks

Comment: How did you compare with the GooglePlay version. Man It will be appreciated

Comment: What I do is to have the latest version in the internet, for example yourdomain.com/lastversion.txt. When the app starts it performs an http get to the url where the latest version is written down and compares with the app version, if the remote version is higher then I launch the intent. So after your version is approved from Google play I update yourdomain.com/lastversion.txt contents with the new released version.

Comment: User this way

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

Answer (score 8):

**Just found a way that works.** Fire an Intent for a Market that searches for my application.

Tested with OpenIntent Newsreader because for it was easy to find an older version .apk. Market finds an application, and when user clicks install, replaces older version with the one from the Market. I think that is much easier solution for a user than downloading manually .apk and running it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW ,Uri.parse("market://search?q=" + APPLICATION_NAME));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: And what if there's no Market (i.e. Google Apps) on device?

Comment: All my users should have Market installed. I guess, if that isn't the case, Jorgesys's answer is the only option.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way to update those instances that are not downloaded through Google Play, since Google Play won't notify users about an update.

Old question, new answer:

After digging on exact the same question (pre-installed app on device, how can I provide a update through Google-Play) I found this information on [support.google.com](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113476&topic=2365760&ctx=topic)*:

> Google Play can manage updates to preloaded applications, provided the following conditions are met:
>
> - The preloaded app needs to be in the system partition
> - The preloaded app needs to be free
> - The preloaded app needs to be signed with the same signature as the app published in Google Play
> - The Package Name of the preloaded and updated app needs to be the same
> - The Version Code of the updated app needs to be greater than that of the preloaded app

* as of 2015-04-13

Comment: As of 10/10/13, one of the requirements is "The preloaded app needs to be free".

Answer (score 4):

> I'm developing an application that
>   will most likely be preinstalled on
>   devices.

Then you need to be talking to the device manufacturers and asking them your questions. Nobody else will be able to tell you what is and is not possible, given their device and the carrier(s) that will distribute it. The answers will depend heavily on how they create their firmware, whether your application will be part of the firmware or "installed" as a normal app, what their arrangement with the carrier is *vis a vis* firmware updates, etc. You may not even get a vote in the matter.

Comment: "You may not even get a vote in the matter." 

I don't... That's why I'm looking for an alternative way... :P

Comment: Maybe you can update your answer and point to your cwac-updater

Comment: @CommonsWar can we auto update lanucher app from google play? I am facing issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504146/google-play-auto-update-does-not-update-apps#39504146

Answer (score 2):

Here is the option for latest version update

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#update_readiness

try this google library to update from the application

```
 dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.5.0'
...}
```

I hope this will help anyone

Comment: This answer is correct, But this solution only works for Android 21 >=

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

Answer (score 1):

If whoever bundled the app on the device does a proper job of it, then the app will still have a market link (even as a system app) and Market will prompt the user to upgrade it if a new version is available. After all, that's exactly what happens with an app like GMail that's pre-installed on phones.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install or upgrade a package automatically.  Only the Android Market is capable of doing this (i.e. it silently updates itself).

You can certainly download a package and fire the `Intent` to install it, but the user will have to have the "Allow non-Market apps" options enabled, and they'll still have to manually approve the install/upgrade.

One place to possibly investigate is how Google Maps does it.  This is generally pre-installed, but always appears to be shown as an update in the Android Market app, I believe.  Whether there's a special flag in the `packages.xml` or manifest, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice service that helps your app keep itself updated. Take a look at https://www.pushlink.com

In this product there is a NINJA mode that allows to perform updates without user interaction.

For other "modes", enabling "Install non-market app" is still needed. If it not enabled, the installation process is going to ask for it and redirect the user to the Application Settings, and after that, the user can install the app.

Comment: Can you lead me to some documentation or to a blog or something about this Ninja mode, so i can dig it little more? Thank you.

Comment: And an expensive one at that! 5000 installs is 1250 a month, and it goes *up*.  Kinda outrageous, but if you are a silly corporate then ok.  Target is probably a small installed base of a private app.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to fully automatically update an app, if you can sign an app as a system app. We wrote an app for specific hardware, we created an update app that the manufacturer signed for us. The update app runs on device startup, checks current version of the app and the new version, and installs the new version if necessary.

The use case would be a kiosk app, on tablets of one make and model, that don't have Google Play.

Answer (score -1):

Google in 2018 Android dev summit announced android in-app update api's for developers so you can read whole story out here and get updated on this question.[Android in-app update api details](https://medium.com/@rizvan/android-in-app-update-feature-404d3e2a0486)

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

Comment: That article has no links to official docs and neither does this answer.