# How to make you app refresh if you are not on Android market?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android app not in Market: how to push updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516133/android-app-not-in-market-how-to-push-updates)

I am not shure, if this is the right forum to ask, but still I try. Did any one encounter the requrement to make it's app refresh itself from a given server? I am developing an application that is supposed to support some mobile survey process. I am not allowed to publish my application via Android Market, but from time to time I have to refresh it with feature enhancements and bug fixes.

Is there any best pracice for this how to do? Do I have to implement a second application that checks for update and reinstalls my mobile app on the smartphoen?

TIA, Tamas Szecsy

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any best pracice for this how to do?

Have your program check some URL on some Web server to find out the latest version of the app (e.g., downloads an XML or JSON file). If there is a newer version, download it in the background to external storage. Once downloaded, display a `Notification` letting the user know an update is ready to install. When they click that, fire off an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` pointing to your APK file and supplying the correct MIME type, which will trigger the update process.