# android application updates

Tags: android, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to automatically update application on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057771/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-application-on-android)

I am looking to create a private android application for my organization. I do not want to publish it publicly on Google Play, since it is only being used for internal purposes. 
Is there a way to have the application auto-update? 
Or, is there a way to publish an app to Google play and make it private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a way on Market to filter for private groups.

I'd recommend the following:
-Host your apk on a private server
-Have a URL on said server where the app can ping to check the version number of the latest available apk.

When newer version is found:
-Download it to specific location using [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).
-Throw a message in the user's notification bar using [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html)
-Set it up so that when user clicks on that notification, an install prompt for that apk file appears.  Details for that are in [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android).

Comment: great, thank you.  But how can i get the apk version from an apk file? some sort of binary reader?

Comment: You mean determining what version is currently on the server?  It'd be total overkill to download the apk and dissect it to find a version number-  Just put a text file up on the server, and increment the value inside it as part of your build/publish process.

Comment: yeah thats what i was thinking... crazy to go digging through binary code for the version.... thanks so much for your help, i think this will be a great solution!

Comment: can we update the installed application in background, without any user actions?

Comment: You can delegate to a third part services like http://www.pushlink.com or other...