# Android. Updating app quietly

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android application updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343412/android-application-updates)

My application needs to be updated from ftp quietly, without user interaction.  Is it possible on rooted device?

Comment: Why? That sounds... suspicious.

Comment: Newer versions of android market allow apps to update automatically without interaction assuming they don't require permissions changes.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It makes no sense unless you're up to something dodgy..

Comment: I would agree that releasing something that does this to the public is dodgy. However I would contend that there are situations when an application is being created for a very specific purpose and not for the general public that this behavior can be both very helpful, and not nefarious in anyway. That being said if I ever observed an application do this on my personal device it would get uninstalled immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Well, on a rooted device you can just mount the filesystem rw and change the APK. That would be without user interaction.