# How to update Android application through our application without go to android  Market?

Tags: android

I have android app, that version is 1.0. There are some updates so changed the version number to 1.1. I did not upload into android market.

It's a private application. 
Normally update app happens like this: If there is version number which differs from installed app, then I should update. That time It don't delete my database contents

is it?

How we can update into version without publishing into android market?

because my applications sales person going use.when there are in the fields(on way to go shop or anywhere their-self want to update)

If there are new version is available then In sql server database also we mention the flag "1" (bacause of sales person can identify there are update version is available)then It should download apk & need to update the system automatically?

OR

when we launch the app,It should check the version number or update available, then should update automatically..

How we can do it?

OR give me a idea of update the android apps..

How we can do this?

Please help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please precise your question, i don't understand it. why do you talk about uploading it to Android Market if it's a private app?

Comment: This is the new to me.I want to update the app without going to the android market.I have button it automatically need to update the application.How is possible?

Comment: I also need a help for this.Try one this....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057771/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-application-on-android

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a versioning system on your server.
Check the current version by calling your servers and checking if there's an update.
If there is an update, download the new APK from your servers through the app by calling the browser on the APK's URL.
This will start a download automatically.

A few problems:
1) Some devices rename the APK to txt for some unexplained reason, I think it has something to do with mime-types

2) The installation won't happen automatically. The user will have to click on the finished downlaod to start the installation.

3) You'll have to check the "Unknown Sources" in the Settings -> Applications menu to allow apps to be installed from outside sources (not the Android Market)

Comment: Point 2 you have mentioned is contrary to the Android Documentation here http://pages.citebite.com/i9o4a0i6jmwx.

Comment: I guess that if you click on an APK file on your browser, the browser is smart enough to install the app after downloading it. In the question's case, the download is initiated through the app and not the browser, which means that all it does is fetch the APK. From there on, the user has to click on the download in order to install it.