# is autoupdating possible in Android without using android market?

Tags: android, auto-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to automatically update application on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057771/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-application-on-android)

As a property of an application(NOT USING GOOGLE PLAY), an auto-updating possible in android?
I mean can a application check and download the new apk file, and install after downloading it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the CWAC-Updater project: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater

Comment: really great and easy to use! Kudos to Mark Murphy

Comment: Link is broken, updated link - https://github.com/gauravarora/cwac-updater

Comment: @Jaydev  this link is broken too

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to maintain you own update server, you may try this: [auto-update-apk.com](http://www.auto-update-apk.com/)

[Android client](http://code.google.com/p/auto-update-apk-client/) is open-source under [Apache 2.0 license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0), so you may see how it works and make any changes, if necessary, before incorporating into your own project or using it as a starting point of your project.

Comment: Love it, and they offer 1GB of monthly bandwidth for free, with a nice web interface to manage your apps. To incorporate in your project, add three permissions in the manifest, copy-paste a Java class and call its constructor. It's that simple!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use your own webservice for checking updates, and open link to new apk in browser. After downloading user can install new version.