# Default app update

Tags: android, google-play

I have a lower version app installed as default app. I have a higher version of app in Google Play.

They have the same certificate. I would update the app in device automatically from Google Play. I saw the similar post below: Prompt Android App User to Update App if current version <> market version [Is there a way to automatically update application on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057771/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-application-on-android) but Neither of those posts answer this question. They mush have some solution. just like Goole Maps, Gmail,Pluse news and Adobe Flash player 11 do. I don't know how Google Play App can display it and how they get updated automatically?  Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upgrade applications automatically...

There is an option in google play "Allow automatic updating". If user select this settings for your app, then it will updated automatically.

I believe for Google Maps, this settings might be turned on by default.