# Updating my android application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to automatically update application on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057771/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-application-on-android)

How to make an android application check for updates and install the updated version over the existing application without the need to uninstall it?

Answer (score 2):

In your Manifest you need to mention

Version Code as lets say 1

and later releases you update it  to a number greater than 1 indicating its an update

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.package.name"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1">
```

read more here http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

If its on market you do not need to worry about the checking part . Just upload your new apk with updated version code on market and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

That is something Google Play automatically does for you when you've published your application to it.

The user will either get a "New Update available"-notification, and install the update when he/she is ready, or they will have configured Google Play to automatically install new updates.

And no need to uninstall the old app.

Comment: buddy i hope that same package name, signing etc and a diff version number is required ;)

Comment: Well of course, that's a given, it's like android development 101.

Comment: yap so either of them dont sync the application will have to be reinstalled for the update so i think that question counts when you are a new bee in android