# How to enable auto-update for my Android apk?

Tags: android, updates

I've developed a simple Android application that will be running in a few tablets. It's not in the market - every app is installed manually. Some time in a future I might want to make some changes, but I can't ask every user to update, so it should update itself. Is this possible?

Comment: here you can find your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057771/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-application-on-android

Comment: Store your current version. Create a web service which return current app version stored in your server(and download link). A function at app start up will check this service. If your device version older than server's version. Download it and ask user to replace. I used this way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible on a stock device. The best you can do is download a new APK file and launch an intent to open it, which will take the user to the Package Installer to press 'Install' or 'Cancel'

If your devices are rooted and you can get write access to `/data/app/` then you can download the apk file and paste it into that directory to "install" it.