# Force user to upgrade the application for further use

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, e-commerce, android-notifications

I have 1 e-commerce application. I added some new feature in my next version. so how to force the user to upgrade the application. and make them unable to use the app. until unless they upgrade the application. I have GCM integration also in my application. so please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automatically update application on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057771/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-application-on-android)

Comment: @YusufK. actually problem is little bit different. That application is already in play store, and many people are using that, but now we released new version of that application with some new feature which will work in new version only. but problem is some user are not updating application and they are continuing with older version. so i want him to force to upgrade the application. so how to do?

Comment: ok, got it. So if your application need a server, maybe you shutdown current server and new version may use new server. And send them a GCM message to inform them. Otherwise; you can't interfere currently installed apps.

Comment: @YusufK. excatly correct, same thing we are going. we changeed the server URL , and older server is now shutdown, so if any user will use older application , then he will not get data. so we are planning to send GCM notification to update the application. just help 1 more thing, that can  we logout or restrict the opening of application through GCM , until unless he upgrade the app.

Comment: you can't, there is no access any code part without update app. GCm sends only text messages to notify user

Answer (score 0):

What I think can be one of your approach is to [send an upstream message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream) (provided you're using [XMPP connection server](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs)) with the `appVersion`. The server will reply (basically a [downstream message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream)) to it to check if its using the latest version. Once the application receives it, it will just call an activity that states that you need to update the application or just continue with the original flow.