# Google play auto update does not update apps

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, auto-update, android-launcher

I have make application as Home & launcher app with below manifest, When i set my application as default Launcher it will not auto update from google play, All other app auto update fine but only one application is not update

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Play does not update the app that is currently running. I am guessing users dislike when the app they are using restarts.

Answer (score -2):

'Auto Update' feature is from Android Play store itself, apps has nothing to do with it.  User can anytime overwrite it from play store settings, to not allow app's to autoupdate.

Comment: it's ok to give -ve vote ,atleast explain why it's voted as incorrect answer.