# Is it possible to notify user by email when a new production app version is released to Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Is there any setting in the Google Play Store Console where I can add a list of emails which should receive an email with information about the app when a new production version of Android app is released?

Comment: Have you added those emails as a Tester?

Comment: The app is released via Production Track. Is it possible at all to have testers for this track? Doesn't a tester list work only for Alpha, Beta, and Internal release tracks?

Comment: Sorry my bad i thought about beta. For your solution did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057771/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-update-application-on-android)?

Comment: No worries. It was my bad. I haven't defined question precisely enough. Thing is I need to do this via email. :) I know a user can enable automatical app update via the Play Store app on the device. Thanks for the hint though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Because of the danger of Spam, the Play Store doesn't do this. If you need a solution for this you will need to write your own.